# Data migration from one org to another

Tags: data, migration

I'm looking to find what would be the best way to migrate millions of records from one org to another (prod to prod). Eg. I have 7+ million cases to move and related Accounts, and other data.

1. Is using external id with old orgs Id a better way to handle relationships? Including user mapping to owner of records?
2. Is there a way to calculate the time it would take to migrate my data (like mbps etc)? This is also to calculate our approximate or minimum down time as well.

Note: I've tried jitterbit before for another migration of data from a sandbox to another sandbox / prod. But the volume was in little over couple of hundred records.

Appreciate experts' suggestion on this.

Comment: Hi Bergin, you should take a look at CopyStorm and CopyStormRestore (www.capstorm.com) tools (SFDC->localdb->SFDC). From my experience CopyStorm handles relationships quite well, so it might suit your needs in that regards. Downside is that it's licensed on per org basis, so in your scenario with two production orgs, you might be looking at 4x licensing costs (2x CopyStorm licenses and 2x CopyStormRestore licenses). There is however a free 30-day trial to asses whether it's really something you would be happy with.

Answer (score 2):

*Full disclosure: I work for Import2*

We offer an automated solution for migrating data from one instance to another. We take care of the mappings and testing for you. We also retain all of the object relationships and ownership during the transfer.

Furthermore, we don't have a limit to how many records we can transfer, so your database size is not an issue.

If you'd like to give it a try, we offer a free sample so you can see a preview with your own data:  https://www.import2.com/salesforce/from/salesforce